# Running an xterm remotely with ssh -Y, defies the coloring I setup in .Xresources

Tags: ssh, xterm, remote-desktop, x-resources

The `xterm` seems to not read the colors I set in my ~/.Xresources file when I connect to a Linux PC remotely.

Basically, if I'm sitting in front of my PC and I run an `xterm` from Xsession, the colors will obey whatever is in my ~/.Xresources file - no problem there.
Here is my ~/.Xresources file:

```
XTerm*background: black
Xterm*XtDefaultBackground: black
Xterm*XtDefaultForeground: white
XTerm*foreground: white
```

But if I log on to that same computer remotely and run an `xterm` (which will appear locally though), the colors are again the default (black fonts on white background).

It seems irrational that `xterm` does not read .Xresources file in this case!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resources are stored in the X server - this is to prevent need for distributing the configuration files across several computers. `.Xresources` was never meant to be read by the applications, it is loaded into the X server with `xrdb` (although the situation is slightly more unclear when it comes to the older `.Xdefaults`, AFAICT). See [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources) for explanation.

That said, your remote XTerm tries to get its resources from your local X server, probably doesn't find them and resorts to defaults (which is black text on white background). Either load the desired settings with `xrdb -merge` into your Xserver or use XTerm options to achieve the desired effect: `xterm -bg black -fg grey`

As a side note: if you are running `xterm` remotely, chances are that a terminal multiplexer (e.g. `tmux` or `screen`) running on the remote machine might do you a better service.

Comment: hi there, i have tried the latter, but i lose all $LS_COLORS gui-ness if i hardcode the colors with -bg & -fg). I have copied the .Xresources file between the 2 computers and i still get the problem. xterm doesn't even read the local Xeserver .Xresources file. Finally i tried running xrdb -merge and then xterm and it works! thank you

Comment: @nass As I mentioned, `.Xresources` **is not** scanned by X applications. `.Xdefaults` might be (at least under some circumstances). On a related note, keeping application settings under (distributed) version control might help you - you can easily get it to multiple machines (just by cloning a repository) - the only thing one needs to take care of is ensuring that the files end up where applications expect them - usually by symlinking (which in turn can be done by a script packed in the repository).